# Not removing particular item in Arraylist

Tags: android, arraylist, android-linearlayout, android-imageview, android-edittext

[image]
   I have a `EditText` with `ImageView Plus` .

1. On click of `ImageView Plus`  I'm inflating new layout with `EditText`  and `ImageView Minus`.
2. Now, On Click of `ImageView Minus`. I want to remove the inflated layout. How to do this?

   ```
   ArrayList<View> viewList;
   /* Inflating new Layout */
   case R.id.ivPlus:
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
               .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       addView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_edit, null);
       viewList.add(addView);
       ll.addView(addView);
       break;
   /* Removing the inflated layout */
   for (int i = 0; i < viewList.size(); i++) {
       final int j = i;
       ImageView minus= (ImageView ) viewList.get(j).findViewById(R.id.ivMinus);
       minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {

               LinearLayout extra_add = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.lin_add);

               extra_add.removeViewAt(j);
           }
       });
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, just replace your method like this and enjoy

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.button_add:
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View addView = layoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.inflate_layout, null);
        viewList.add(addView);
        lin_layout.addView(addView);
        Button remove = (Button) addView.findViewById(R.id.button_remove);
        remove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                lin_layout.removeView((View) v.getParent());
                viewList.remove((View) v.getParent());
            }
        });
        break;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, but without giving findviewbyid, how will it recognize which view/content to delete??

Comment: Is that a large class? Can you post code and I will correct for you? I am in a hurry now so don't have much time to poke in the dark :)

Comment: You are welcome, any time, once again sorry for the slow way, but I'm in the middle of something :)

Comment: Hi!I want to toast  edittext content of inflated layout on clicking a Submit button. how to do this?

Comment: Try this `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();`

Comment: well its toasting only for the last ediitext item.. see my another question here.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666045/dynamically-adding-views-and-toasting-it